# How to use rspec for a java application using jruby?

Tags: java, rspec, jruby

I have a simple spring mvc application that I want to test with using rspec and cucumber (or with rspec's integration testing features).

How do I go about importing my java war file so rspec can use it?

Any suggestions on folder structure also?

I'm using maven also, so I have this so far:

```
/project_name/src/main
/project_name/src/main/java
/project_name/src/main/webapp
/project_name/src/main/test
/project_name/src/main/resources
```

Should I add rspec and cucumber like:

```
/project_name/spec
/project_name/features
```

I'm confused how rspec will be able to import my java libs?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the package is built, then:

```
require 'java'
require "/some/path/\*.jar" 
instance = Java::my.package.MyClass.new
instance.should be
```

https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby

Comment: My project doesn't have a .jar file, it is spring mvc application which compiles to a exploded war.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [Ginkgo4j](http://paulcwarren.github.io/ginkgo4j/)?  It a Java port of RSpec that allows you to test the same way as RSpec, just in Java.

Add this dependency to your POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>ginkgo4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Create a JUnit test case specifying the Ginkgo4jRunner runner:

```
@RunWith(Ginkgo4jRunner.class)
@Ginkgo4jConfiguration(threads = 1)
public class MyTest {
  {
    Describe("ClassUnderTest", () -> {
      Context("#Method", () -> {
        BeforeEach(() -> {
          // before test logic          
        }); 
        JustBeforeEach(() -> {
          ClassUnderTest.Method();          
        }); 
        Context("given a context", () -> {
          It("should do something", () -> {
            // assertions
          });
        });
        Context("given a different context", () -> {
          It("should do something else", () -> {
            // assertions
          });
        });
        AfterEach(() -> {
          // after test logic
        });
      });
    }); 
  }
}
```